# How to add a value to an Object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's take an example in javascript

```
var b = function(){
        var key = {};
        var result = [];

        var a = 
        [{people: "people1"},
        {people: "people2"},
        {people: "people2"},
        {people: "people3"}]

        for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
         {
            var val = a[i][people];
            if(angular.isUndefined(key[val]))
            {
               Key[val] = "abc"; /////This line is foreign to my knowledge.

               result.push(val);
            }
         }
        return result;
    }
```

Now in this Example i am creating an object **Key** and a array **result**.

The for loop will loop through the **a variable** and store the value of **people property** in the **var val**.

The angular.Isundefined function check whether the **key[val]** contains any duplicate data if not then it will add using the

**Key[val] = "abc"**.

1) Now i have no idea how this line is creating the value and key pair in the **key** object.

2) Please tell me other ways to add value to the object.

O/P is as follows

```
  key = Object {people1: abc, people2: abc, people3: abc}
```

hence it is adding value to **key** object without duplicating the value.

P.S. it is just an example not the real code.

Comment: "in this Example i am creating a **Json object** Key": No, that's an object. JSON would be a string representation of an object - hence the name: [JavaScript Object Notation](http://json.org). There is nothing like a "JSON object"

Comment: `var val = a[i][people];` has to be `var val = a[i]["people"];`, `Key[val] = "abc"` Javascript is case sensitive. `Key != key`

Comment: [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: yea thats an object and the name is key that is why it is bolded

Comment: Thanks for the link it is helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

in the following example i add count in my json my json come from ajax but i want to add count so add count below code that's work fine for me here .count is my custom value added by me, it is not part of my response

```
$scope.data = response.items;
for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
    response.items[i].count = i;                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the link of **Andreas** in comments

I think this solves my problem.

the other way to add the key and value to the JSON object is like this.

```
obj = {};
obj[people1] = "data";
obj[people2] = "data";
obj[people3] = "data";
console.log(obj);
```

The key cannot be same but the value can be same.

So this is what my question was

```
Key[val] = "abc";
```

this line is getting the **val variable** dynamically and adding the **val variable** as the key and the value is **abc**.

Twist:

Do you think that

```
key.val = "abc";
```

work?

No:
This is what provided by the site

Any property name that is not a valid JavaScript identifier (for example, a property name that has a space or a hyphen, or that starts with a number)

can only be accessed using the square bracket notation. This notation is also very useful when property names are to be dynamically determined (when the property name is not determined until runtime).

Comment: Here key in obj Json object is people1, people2 and people3

Comment: `var val = "a"; key[val] = "abc"` and `key.a = "abc"` mean the same thing. Put it another way, `key["val"]` is the same as `key.val`

Comment: They are same but not if properties are defined at run time.

Comment: No, you don't get it. They are the same. Look at the examples closely: `a["b"]` is the same as `a.b` but not the same as `a[b]`